# Can't modify my default theme in MU with React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Trying to modify my theme with React and typescript but I'm getting an error when adding a new key in my theme object. See below:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

enum themePalette {
  ARCBLUE = "#0B72B9",
  ARCORANGE = "#FFBA60",
}

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    common: {
      blue: "#0B72B9"
    },
    primary: {
      main: themePalette.ARCBLUE,
    },
    secondary: {
      main: themePalette.ARCORANGE,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

The error says:

[image]

For JS it works. I'm not sure if it has something to do with defining the types? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#custom-variables ?

Comment: @KimSkovhusAndersen Yes, I did. The error disappears but the UI remains the same.

Comment: you probably need to name it main, light or dark instead of blue